# is there any replacement for the deprecated $php_errormsg variable?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-7.2

I'm currently learning about errors in php, specifically `track_errors` runtime variable and the related `$php_errormsg` variable.

However, when I checked the documentation for `$php_errormsg`, it mentions that it is deprecated as of php 7.2.0

[image]

So is there any equivalent replacement that can be used in place of `$php_errormsg`?

Comment: `error_get_last();` returns an array.

Comment: yeah, [the manual's](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php) docs on this really doesn't help anybody by simply telling people to not rely on it and not giving an alternate method. I'd send them something about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
echo error_get_last()['message'];
```

Comment: The function can return NULL...